# The java eclipse eventsystem only works when there is a print function

Tags: java, eclipse, events, button, mouse

I have a class that handles all the mouse events, this way it's very easy to check if a mouse button is clicked, but it seems to only work when I add this line: `system.out.println(mouseManager.getMouseX());`.

The MouseManager class:

```
public class MouseManager implements MouseListener, MouseMotionListener {

    private boolean leftPressed, rightPressed;
    private int mouseX, mouseY;

    public MouseManager() {

    }

    public boolean isLeftPressed() {
        return leftPressed;
    }

    public boolean isRightPressed() {
        return rightPressed;
    }

    public int getMouseX() {
        return mouseX;
    }

    public int getMouseY() {
        return mouseY;
    }

    @Override
    public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent e) {
        mouseX = e.getX();
        mouseY = e.getY();

    }

    @Override
    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
        if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON1) {
            leftPressed = true;
        }
        else if (e.getButton() == MouseEvent.BUTTON3) {
            rightPressed = true;

        }
    }

}
```

As you can see the MouseManager class is very simple, but it's used to get called within other classes to make mouse inputs easier.
**But** in the Visuals class (which isn't an appropriate name, it's more of the main class) things go wrong.

```
public void Update() {
    if (mouseManager.isLeftPressed()) {
        Vector2 posClicked = GetRoundedMousePos();
        int index = GetPosInArray(posClicked);
        System.out.println(Grid.cells.get(index).cellType.toString());

        if (Grid.cells.get(index).cellType == Cell.CellType.GROUND) {
            Grid.cells.get(index).cellType = Cell.CellType.SAND;
            repaint();
        }
    }
    System.out.println(mouseManager.getMouseX());
}
```

As you can see I added `prinln` to make sure it works.

**NOTE:**

- I only show the Update method, because the whole script is too long
- The Update method is called every frame
- mouseManager is declared above with this line: `private static MouseManager mouseManager = new MouseManager();`

Without `System.out.println(mouseManager.getMouseX());` at the bottom of Update, `mouseManager.isLeftPressed()` doesn't work. So how to fix that?

**AND** this may be related to the bug above, but even with the `println()` function the mouseManager seems to not always detect mouse presses.

Comment: Random guess: this is because mouse updates are occurring on another Thread and there is no explicit handling for this - try making your fields `volatile` as a test. I'm also suspicious of this _static_ `MouseManager` - why not a `private final` instance?

Comment: What is volatile and which fields? And I made it final instead of static, but it doesn't do anything now, so I changed it back to private static.

Comment: `private volatile boolean leftPressed, rightPressed; private volatile int mouseX, mouseY;`

Comment: Yep that works, thank you! I only have one issue and I hope you can help me with that too, but I first have to edit the question so please wait.

Comment: I don't need any help anymore thank you a lot! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mouse updates are occurring on another Thread and there is no explicit handling for this. Volatile fields are probably all you need here given the uni-directional flow of information from MouseManager to caller:

```
private volatile boolean leftPressed, rightPressed;
private volatile int mouseX, mouseY;
```

As an aside, you should look at replacing that `static` class-field with a `final` instance-field (and further, passing it in as a constructor argument):

```
private final MouseManager mouseManager = new MouseManager();
```

Comment: Yeah that works, just what drekbour was saying above in the comments. But thank you anyways.
NOTE: Using `final` instead of `static` doesn't work.